# Diagnosing server-side ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERRORs

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, diagnostic

I'm copying my website's production environment to local development, and getting "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". All the debugging advice I'm digging up assumes the website is flawless, and the problem is on the browser side.

When you're sure the problem is on the server side, how do you get Chrome to cough up a more useful error message, to get to a solution faster?

Comment: You likely don't get a better error message. Such problems are unfortunately hard to debug. But often a good understanding of how TLS works and what kind of problems usually happen combined with a packet capture will help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: You might find more details in Chrome using chrome://net-export/ but a paket capture is probably the most useful.